# Optimal path player movement in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What I'm trying to do here, is for character to move to a position while avoiding obstacles in his path. I tried to use something like this:

```
// node = character 
// position = position of touch

[self.map enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"tile" usingBlock:^(SKNode * _Nonnull tileNode, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {        
    if( round((SDistanceBetweenPoints(node.position, tileNode.position)) < 33) ) {
        if((SDistanceBetweenPoints(tileNode.position, position) < newDistance)&&((tileNode.position.x == position.x) || (tileNode.position.y == position.y))) {
            newDistance = SDistanceBetweenPoints(tileNode.position, position);
            moveToTouch = tileNode.position;
        }
    }
}];
```

And my main problem with this is that character starts walking right at half way up:

[image]

Comment: SKSpriteNodes's coordinated are based on the center of the Sprite, not the top left corner like UIViews. Can you try the same code with this consideration in mind?

Comment: well... That indeed solved my problem!  Thanks! (Post as an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SKSpriteNodes's coordinated are based on the center of the Sprite, not the top left corner like UIViews. Try the same code with this consideration in mind.